# 5 Tables -> Displaying Certain Distinct Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, outer-join

I'm pulling information that will eventually be from 5 tables at once based off of a filtering system. Right now I have three different databases running, its looking great. My issue is I have certain fields that I only want to display distinct information on and others i want to display all. To better explain I'm going to give my example.

My select code:

```
SELECT w.event,
       w.city,
       w.DATE,
       a.TIME,
       w.tmc,
       a.weather,
       a.surface_temperature,
       p.top,
       p.LEFT
FROM   weather w
       LEFT OUTER JOIN application a
         ON a.DATE = w.DATE
            AND a.tmc = w.tmc
       LEFT OUTER JOIN pinlocations p
         ON w.city = p.cityname
WHERE  w.DATE = '" & datepicker_value.Text & "'
       AND w.TIME LIKE '" & eventTime.SelectedItem.Value & "'
```

I have a map which I'm placing pins on based of the p.top and p.left. When I click on this I want to display the city name, the tmc, and then under that all the other information based off the filtered search. In the example above it creates pins on top of pins, making a new one for each field, I want it to be distinct.

I know the distinct command exists, just not sure how to use it in this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for making it look prettier :)

Comment: The problem is that your results are likely already distinct anyways, so adding the keyword won't help.  This actually sounds more like an application-layer issue - every time you go to create a new pin, check first to see if one in the same position exists, and update it if necessary.

Comment: First of all, you are using concatenation in your SQL query which is *[EXTREMELY DANGEROUS](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=sql+string+concatenation+injection&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4e0d51cc84241161&biw=1680&bih=883)* and *[EXTREMELY BAD PRACTICE](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sa=X&ei=09tTTrXxBoaDtgf_npnmBQ&ved=0CBUQvwUoAQ&q=sql+string+concatenation+bad+practice&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4e0d51cc84241161&biw=1680&bih=883)* because of [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I recommend you use parameters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `group by` modifier, on the values you want to be distinct.
Then use a `group_concat` on the values you want to have listed in a comma-separated list.

```
SELECT group_concat(w.event) as events,
       group_concat(w.city) as cities,
       group_concat(w.`DATE`) as dates,
       group_concat(a.`TIME`) as times,
       group_concat(w.tmc) as tmcs,
       group_concat(a.weather) as weathers,
       group_concat(a.surface_temperature) as temperatures,
       p.top,
       p.LEFT
FROM   weather w
       LEFT OUTER JOIN application a
         ON a.DATE = w.DATE
            AND a.tmc = w.tmc
       LEFT OUTER JOIN pinlocations p
         ON w.city = p.cityname
WHERE  w.DATE = '" & datepicker_value.Text & "'
       AND w.TIME LIKE '" & eventTime.SelectedItem.Value & "'  
GROUP BY p.top, p.left
```

If a left-top coordinate only ever links to one city *(as you'd expect)*, there's no need to put it inside a `group_concat` statement. Nor does MySQL require* you to put it in the `group by` clause.

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

** ) you can force MySQL do enforce strict group by rules, but by default it is off.*

You cannot use `distinct` here, because distinct is an all or nothing affair, it operates in the collectivity of all selected values, not just on one field.

Comment: How do I go about calling the information using this method? My approach of:

<%#Container.DataItem("tmc")%>

no longer works

Comment: You can use `explode` to extract the items from a comma separated list in php, what are you using BTW?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Thanks so much! I'm using vb, its required for this project for work. And i need to pull from the group name now not the original field name (duh)!

Comment: One more question. for tmcs its iffy.

Cities like fort wayne only have 1 tmc so it works fine. Cities like indianapolis have several tmcs, but i still want them all to be just defined once under the indianapolis pin.

Is there a way to do something like DISTINCT(group_concat(w.tmc)) ?